# Help generate useful solutions with Solve

Tags: equation-solving, coordinate-transformation, constraint

I have the Equations for converting between cartesian and spherical polar coordinates

```
eqns = {u*Sin[v]*Cos[w], u*Sin[v]*Sin[w], u*Cos[v]} == {x, y, z};
```

when I try to solve these using the Solve command and not implementing the constraints on the spherical coordinates, the system is solved almost immediately albeit the solution set contains undetermined constants and solutions not applicable to the problem I am trying to solve.

```
In[24]:=
Sols1 = Solve[eqns, {u, v, w}]

Out[24]= {{u -> -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
  v -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[-(z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]), -(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[
       x^2 + y^2 + z^2])] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers], 
  w -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 2 \[Pi] C[2], 
    C[2] \[Element] Integers]}, {u -> -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
  v -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[-(z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]), Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers], 
  w -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[-(x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]), -(y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])] + 2 \[Pi] C[2], 
    C[2] \[Element] Integers]}, {u -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
  v -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[z/Sqrt[
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2], -(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])] + 
     2 \[Pi] C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers], 
  w -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[-(x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]), -(y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])] + 2 \[Pi] C[2], 
    C[2] \[Element] Integers]}, {u -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
  v -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]] + 
     2 \[Pi] C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers], 
  w -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 2 \[Pi] C[2], 
    C[2] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

I tried implementing the constraints directly into the Solve command like this;

```
In[22]:=
Sols2 =Solve[{eqns, u > 0, 0 < v < Pi, 0 < w < 2*Pi}, {u, v, w}]; 

Out[22]= $Aborted
```

but after 30 mins I had to abort the calculation as my computer was overheating.

Is there a quick way to produce the solution I am looking for or at least filter the output of the initial calculation based on constraints.

Ps I know I could use the CoordinateTransform function in this case but I would like to generalise this method for use with non-standard coordinate transformations.

Thanks